# Compute Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $s, \alpha$ and $k$ be a real numbers. I would like tu compute the following integral 
$$
I=\int_{0}^{x}(\alpha^kz)^{-s}dz.
$$
In my opinion I do as follow 
$$
I=\int_{0}^{x}(\alpha^kz)^{-s}dz.
$$
$$
I=\alpha^{-sk}\int_{0}^{x}z^{-s}dz.
$$
$$
I=\alpha^{-sk}\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}.
$$
But is not the correct result.

Comment: Please if it possible some one can provide me the result to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my approach would be:
$$I=\int_0^x\alpha^{-sk}z^{-s}dz=\alpha^{-sk}\left[\frac{z^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]_0^x$$
but you have to be careful where $s=1$ as it does not follow this general formula, and the bottom of the fraction will not work

Answer (score 0):

The integral does not converge for all values for $s$.

Namely, $s \geq 1$.

For all other values, your expression is correct.